# How to use artisan command and check error in Browser

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using php artisan make:command test  [for example i create command test] If I want to use dd in function handle how can I check the error from terminal into browser

I've try to dd($user) in handle function and when I use php artisan test It's print out  $user which is right

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $user = User::all();
        dd($user);
    }
```

But I've a lot of User and It's very hard to looking all user in terminal . Is their anyway to use command test in terminal and I want it to result in browser  without making a new controller ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have to create one Routing for the run command. as simple we create other routes.

You can try below example.

Create a routing rule in **routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/clear_cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
});

Route::get('/URL_SLUG_OF_YOUR_COMMAND', function() {
    Artisan::call('route:list'); // RUN ANY COMMAND
});
```

Way to call in the browser your command.

http://www.yoursite.com/clear_cache

http://www.yoursite.com/route:list

Same as you can run your command and see the output in a browser if command returns any output.

Comment: thanks this what I looking for. I think I like to debug in Browser more than terminal but Can you give me some advice Why terminal more easily ?

Comment: No i have a great hand on the terminal so i was managed it easily. but I can understand most of the people have not used to with terminal so the browser is good for the debug. 
Cheers, Mate you got it in a browser! :) Tx.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dump($var)` instead of `dd($var)`

Comment: ha ha ha ha !!! Have first understood what he wants to do and what he ask.
Both are doing same thing. dd() is doing the same dump and die.

Comment: Only doing dump will not make it die though

Comment: So if we only do dump then it will be showing on a browser? They have issue terminal is not easy to see output so they need that thing over a browser. for laravel custom commands output.

Comment: I don't know if he wanted to use it for debugging purposes, but yeah it will display a black rectangle with the debbuged data in it ;)